# Routing in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This my routing in rails2 how to change this in rails 3

```
map.resources :users,
  :collection => {
       :sample => :post, 
       :select_ant => :get, 
       :list_ant => :get, 
       :list_mod => :get },
  :member => {
       :new_sample => :get,
       :create_sample => :post,
       :new_sprof=>:get,
       :create_sprof=>:post } do |user|
           user.resources :semails, 
           :collection => { 
               :sort => :get, 
               :save_samplesemail =>  :post }
       end
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    post :sample
    get :select_ant
    get :list_ant
    get :list_mod
  end
  member do
    get :new_sample
    post :create_sample
    get :new_sprof
    post :create_sprof
  end
  resources :semails do
    collection do
      get :sort
      post :save_samplesemail
    end
  end
end
```